# ImageView fills different screen sizes, but maintaing the aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, fullscreen

I have a rectangular image in an image view. I want to fit the image in the screen for **different screen sizes** while maintaining the **aspect ratio**.

In smaller screen its working fine, but its not getting stretched in biggerscreens. Some gap remains in the bottom of the image.

This is my code:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 
LayoutParams params1 = new LayoutParam(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


mMainLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
mMainLayout.setLayoutParams(params);


backgroundImage = new ImageView(context);
backgroundImage.setId(0);
backgroundImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
backgroundImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
backgroundImage.setLayoutParams(params1);
backgroundImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_circles_en); 

mMainLayout.addView(backgroundImage);
```

I have used many combinations of `fill_parent`, `wrap_content` with multiple scaleTypes: `fitCenter`, `centerInside`and they all draw the images in the right aspect ratio, but none of them actually scale the images up and the ImageView itself, resulting in either the TextViews get pushed all the way down off the screen, blank spaces inside the ImageView, or image not scaled.

Please give a right combination so that it will work properly for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Privide ScaleType FIT_XY, it will scale image to x and y dimensions, irrespective of aspect ratio.

Comment: it didnt worked man. I previously tried with that also, but no change. Same some space is there in bottom of the page in bigger screens

Comment: Its because you are setting wrap content layout params to the image view, instead set layout params to params.

Comment: thnx jeet..it worked..but the image is getting stretched towards y axis. how can we rectify that ?

Comment: isnt it you want, you want to scale image to target width and height, irrespective of aspect ratio, not sure but you can use ScaleType Matrix, I think